# Display errors with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, error-handling, thymeleaf

I want to display errors on html page with thymeleaf. But it doesn't work. I post here my entity class, controller class, html page and error page when I save. I only use description for test yet.

recipeform.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  <link th:rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <form  th:object="${recipe}" th:action="@{/save}"  method="post">
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" class="alert alert-danger">
          <p>Please Correct Errors Below</p>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <div class="pannel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">Edit Recipe Information</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('description')}
                                ? 'col-md-3 form-group has-error' : 'col-md-3 form-group'">
                  <label>Recipe Description:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" th:field="*{description}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>
                    <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('description')}">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('description')}" th:text="${err}"/>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Categories:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 form-group">
                  <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                      Cat 1
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="radio" th:remove="all">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                      Cat 2
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Prep Time:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{prepTime}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Cooktime:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{cookTime}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Difficulty:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" th:field="*{difficulty}">
                    <option th:each="difficultyValue : ${T(com.springframeworklessons.recipemain.enums.Difficulty).values()}"
                            th:value="${difficultyValue.name()}"
                            th:text="${difficultyValue.name()}"
                    >val</option>
                  </select>
                  <select class="form-control" th:remove="all">
                    <option>Easy</option>
                    <option>Medium</option>
                    <option>Hard</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Servings:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{servings}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Source:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{source}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>URL:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{url}"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-11 ">
                  <h1 class="panel-title">Ingredients</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Edit</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <ul>
                    <li th:remove="all">1 Cup of milk</li>
                    <li th:remove="all">1 Teaspoon of chocolate</li>
                    <li th:each="ingredient : ${recipe.ingredients}"
                        th:text="${(ingredient.getAmount() +
                                        ' ' + ingredient.unitOfMeasure.getDescription() +
                                        ' - ' + ingredient.getDescription())}">1 Teaspoon of Sugar
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">Directions</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" th:field="*{directions}"></textarea></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">Notes</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" th:field="*{notes.recipeNotes}"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

RecipeController.class

```
private static final String RECIPE_RECIPEFORM_URL = "/recipe/recipeform";

@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveRecipe(@Valid @ModelAttribute("recipe") RecipeCommand recipeCommand, BindingResult bindingResult){

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach(objectError -> {log.debug(objectError.toString());});

        return RECIPE_RECIPEFORM_URL;
    }

    RecipeCommand savedRecipeCommand = recipeService.saveRecipeCommand(recipeCommand);

    return "redirect:recipe/"+savedRecipeCommand.getId()+"/show";
}
```

Recipe.class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe", schema = "public")
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @Column
    @Min(1)
    @Max(999)
    private Integer prepTime;
    @Column
    private Integer cookTime;
    @Column
    private Integer servings;
    @Column
    private String source;

    @Column
    @URL
    private String url;

    @Lob
    @Column
    private String directions;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "recipe")
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients = new HashSet<>();

    @Lob
    @Column
    private Byte[] image;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    private Difficulty difficulty;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Notes notes;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "recipe_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();


    public Recipe addIngredient(Ingredient ingredient){
        ingredient.setRecipe(this);
        this.ingredients.add(ingredient);
        return this;
    }


}
```

This page is showed when I save. I can't find cause. I want the errors to appear in html page.
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJgyZ.png)

Templates
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC4ET.png)

Comment: You are using a redirect which destroyes the model as it will issue a new request, so no errors are there. Don't use a redirect. You shouldn't be saving either if there are errors just return the page to render only redirect after a succesful save.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I edited my controller. But it doesn't work. What is reason?

Comment: You should return the view name not the full URL.

Comment: This is my view name - RECIPE_RECIPEFORM_URL = "/recipe/recipeform"; I added templates folder

Comment: Now you newhere stated you have an exception, you only stated you don't have errors. That exception you get has nothing to do with the view. Apparently there are no errors and you try to save anyway. Do you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` on your classpath? Show your dependencies.